# Abort concat observables at certain point

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm having a list of observables I'd like to call and I'm using a concat to execute them one by one, the problem is that I'd like to stop the concat execution at certain moment after receiving one result

```
const list = [
    this.http.get('someurl'), 
    this.http.get('someurl'), 
    this.http.get('someurl'),
    ...
    ];

concat(list).subscribe((result) => {
     if(result === 3){
        //stop concat and return
     }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `takeWhile` operator:

```js
concat(list).pipe(
  takeWhile(res => res !== 3)
).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `takeWhile` operator:

```
concat(list)
.pipe(takeWhile(result => result !== 3))
.subscribe((result) => {

});
```

Comment: The `takeUntil` operator takes an Observable as an argument. This won't work. You want the `takeWhile` operator, and even then, this isn't quite written properly.

Comment: Your original post was incorrect. I just saw you edited it to correct it.